# My logo does not appear in my title page

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to include my logo on the title page of my thesis. However, it does not appear. All that I got is an empty box with the title of my log!

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    final,
    colorlinks=true, 
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
    }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx} % was missing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{titling}

\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\null\mbox{}\vfill}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookd{\vfill\null}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
    \begin{titlepage}
    \vfill % better
        \begin{center}
            {\huge \bfseries  \@title }\\[2ex] 
            {\LARGE  \@author}\\ [18ex]
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{logo.jpg}\\[2ex]
            {\large \@date}
        \end{center}
        \vfill % better
    \end{titlepage}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

any help, please?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage

Comment: @Maryam: Your updated code works fine for me (TeXLive 2017). No compilation errors occur.

Comment: @Marian G.  I am using Overleaf. Do you think the problem is from the editor itself?

Comment: sounds like you have the `draft` option activated.

Comment: You need to ask a new question however - this is something different than the question you asked before. so my answer does not fit to your question anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright,
demo % comment out
]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    final,
    colorlinks=true, 
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
    }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx} % was missing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{titling}

\author{My Name}% was missing
\title{My Title}% was missing
\date{\today}% was missing

\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\null\mbox{}\vfill}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookd{\vfill\null}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
    \begin{titlepage}
    \vfill % better
        \begin{center}
            {\huge \bfseries  \@title }\\[2ex] 
            {\LARGE  \@author}\\ [18ex]
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{logo.jpg}\\[2ex]
            {\large \@date}
        \end{center}
        \vfill % better
    \end{titlepage}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I add the \makeatother but the problem still arises.

Comment: then you need to give a complete Minimal Working Example (MWE).

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: so did I my answer, a couple of things were missing, comment out `demo` when you compile to omit the black box.